# MYSQL - Not getting results when adding empty foreign key table

Tags: mysql

So I have been having this issue with something.

I have a structure that states a store is in a city.

```
table Stores
store (pk)
city (fk)
```

Getting them works fine.
Then I add store_info

```
table store_info
store (pk)
adress
phone
description
```

so we get this query:

```
SELECT stores.ID, store_info.address, store_info.phone
                        FROM store_info, stores
                        WHERE stores.city = 1
                        AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
```

Now, this is working perfectly fine.
However, the moment I add `FROM store_brands`

```
    SELECT stores.ID, store_info.address, store_info.phone
                        FROM store_info, stores, store_brands, brands
                        WHERE stores.city = 1
                        AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
```

This last query fails to give me results, but the query does not fail.

The thing is, I store my stores apart from the brands, and I link the brands to the stores through means of a relations table (2 foreign keys)
It looks as simple as this:

```
store_brands
  storeID (fk to stores)
  brandID (fk to brands)
```

The whole point of the setup (as you may well be aware) is that I can gather all the brands through use of `GROUP_CONCAT`. The query technically works perfectly fine *as long as the store has at least 1 relationship within the `store_brands` table*

Now, what I want to do is, I want to get the store entirely regardless of whether or not it has linked brands. These same brands can also be linked through the chain (1 level up), so I want to gather both these instances, meaning I still want the store to show up even if it hasn't got any brands filled out.

I don't understand why there HAS to be a row in `store_brands` in order for a simple select query to have it show up. Can anybody help me with this? Am I making a big mistake within my structure?

**Edit for clarity:**
This is the entire query, by the way. It works fine, but again, only works if the store actually has brands linked to it: (the previous queries were debugs as to where it went wrong)

```
SELECT store_info.storeID, store_info.display_name, store_info.address, store_info.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(brands.display_name ORDER BY brands.name) AS brands
                    FROM store_info, brands, stores, store_brands
                    WHERE stores.city = 1
                    AND store_brands.store =  stores.ID
                    AND brands.id = store_brands.brand
                    AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
                    GROUP BY store_info.storeID
                    ORDER BY store_info.display_name
```

**Update and answered**

Thanks to the source provided by **idg**, I found out how I needed to replace my regular joins with left joins, and how this would indeed return NULL.

New, working query:

```
SELECT stores.ID, store_info.display_name, store_info.address, store_info.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(brands.display_name ORDER BY brands.name) AS brands
                        FROM store_info, stores
                        LEFT JOIN store_brands ON stores.ID = store_brands.store
                        LEFT JOIN brands ON store_brands.brand = brands.ID
                        WHERE stores.city = 1
                        AND stores.ID = store_info.storeID
                        GROUP BY store_info.storeID
                        ORDER BY store_info.display_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for cases where null values are allowed. Read up on [how joins work here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Comment: That's one hell of a good source. I tried googling before and didn't find this source, but it's the clearest one I've seen! (at least to me)

I have changed the query and it works now (after some fiddling, of course).

Thank you, kind ser!